# Have only one image for the whole backgroung / style

Tags: html, css

I am new and I try to learn on how to use `html` and `css`.

I know that it is possible to have the whole style of a page (example background image, help buttons etc. ) in order to avoid the overload of the page / cache problem.

Is there any simple example for beginners to learn to use it?

Comment: You are trying to have all the _style_ of the page in just one **file**? or **folder**? or just **one call** in html? what are you exactly looking for?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to have a full size background image then you can check out this neat little tutorial for [Perfect full page background image](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/).

Make sure you have your basic HTML file and add the `<style>` tag within it, so,

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
html { 
background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

</body>
</html>
```

simply replace `background: url(images/bg.jpg)` to the location of your image file.